# What could be causing this file to take so long to compile on the CI build machine, but not on my laptop?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an Objective-C class file which consists, almost entirely, of a single method that returns an `NSDictionary`. The `NSDictionary` is constructed as a very large literal. 5250 lines of literal. Here's an excerpt from somewhere in the middle:

```
-------8<-------
@{
  kSectionKey : year_1982_section,
  kItemsKey : @[
    @{ kItemCode : @"03388", kNameKey : january, kApprovedKey : @YES, kRequiresAuthorizationKey : @NO },
    @{ kItemCode : @"03389", kNameKey : march, kApprovedKey : @YES, kRequiresAuthorizationKey : @NO },
    @{ kItemCode : @"03390", kNameKey : april, kApprovedKey : @YES, kRequiresAuthorizationKey : @NO },
    @{ kItemCode : @"03391", kNameKey : may, kApprovedKey : @YES, kRequiresAuthorizationKey : @NO },
    @{ kItemCode : @"03392", kNameKey : june, kApprovedKey : @YES, kRequiresAuthorizationKey : @NO },
    @{ kItemCode : @"03393", kNameKey : july, kApprovedKey : @YES, kRequiresAuthorizationKey : @NO },
    @{ kItemCode : @"03394", kNameKey : august, kApprovedKey : @YES, kRequiresAuthorizationKey : @NO },
    @{ kItemCode : @"03395", kNameKey : september, kApprovedKey : @YES, kRequiresAuthorizationKey : @NO },
    @{ kItemCode : @"03396", kNameKey : october, kApprovedKey : @YES, kRequiresAuthorizationKey : @NO },
    @{ kItemCode : @"03397", kNameKey : november, kApprovedKey : @YES, kRequiresAuthorizationKey : @NO },
    @{ kItemCode : @"03398", kNameKey : december, kApprovedKey : @YES, kRequiresAuthorizationKey : @NO },
  ]
},
-------8<-------
```

Yes, I know you want to know why we're doing that instead of just loading a JSON or XML file. There are good reasons that I don't want to debate in this forum.

It turns out that compiling this in Xcode on my laptop is really fast. But compiling it as part of our continuous integration is really slow. At least 22 minutes the last time we tried (and canceled).

Any idea why that would be the case? The CI machine is a 2012 Mac Pro with 64 GB RAM and an SSD. The build is kicked off by Jenkins, which runs Xcode via the command line.